# Nginx: Forcing upstream server to log proxy server's request id instead of it's own request id

Tags: nginx, proxypass

I've setup a proxy server that forwards client requests to an upstream server which works fine so far. However, the issue I am trying to solve is that forcing upstream server to log the request id of the proxy server. Is this possible? Just to let you know the `$_SERVER` variable of upstream server contains `[HTTP_X_REQUEST_ID] => 84708dd39a6c0c91e0d1a97404b40f75`

**PROXY SERVER**

CONFIG

```
server {
    ...

    add_header              X-Request-ID       $request_id;
    proxy_set_header        X-Request-ID       $request_id;

    location ~ ^/api/(.*) {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.0.1:8080/$1$is_args$args;
    }

    ...
}
```

LOG FORMAT

```
log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" "$request_id"';
```

LOG

```
172.17.0.1 ...... "84708dd39a6c0c91e0d1a97404b40f75"
```

**UPSTREAM SERVER**

CONFIG

```
server {
    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass php_server:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        internal;
    }
}
```

LOG FORMAT

```
log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" "$request_id"';
```

LOG

```
172.20.0.1 ...... "172.17.0.1" "7376e0cead9741e7ec07a9194efc80e6"
```

***EXPECTED LOG***

```
172.20.0.1 ...... "172.17.0.1" "84708dd39a6c0c91e0d1a97404b40f75"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't actually want the upstream server to log the request ID in `$request_id`. Instead you want it to log the contents of an HTTP request header named `X-Request-ID`.

In that case you should log the variable corresponding to that HTTP request header instead: `$http_x_request_id`.